# Not being able to push data to the object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push the array data to the the object testCities. But I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". This is the code I have tried.

```
var testCities = {};
testCities.type = 'FeatureCollection';
var data = data.data,
    len = data.length;

for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    let name = data[j].name_e + ', ' + data[j].province_e;
    let testCitiesLatitude = data[j].lat_lng.split(',')[0];
    let testCitiesLongitude = data[j].lat_lng.split(',')[1];

    let s = {type: "Feature", properties: {name: name}, geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [testCitiesLongitude, testCitiesLatitude]}}
    testCities.features.push(s)
}
```

I need result like this:

```
var testCities = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "Mo Chit"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            100.5538,
            13.8023
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "Ratchathewi"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            100.5383,
            13.7649
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: The error means exactly what it says.. you do not have any `features` property on your object.

Comment: where do you assign a value to `testCities.features`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have updated my question

Comment: You need to initialize `testCities.features` with an empty list.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes i have tried testCities.features = {}. but i still get same error

Comment: This is wanted behavior. You just cannot go to the grocery store and put stuff into a cart that doesn't exist yet. You can get one and then put stuff in it, though.

Comment: @Frederik.L thank you i understand my mistake

Comment: @user1687891 `{}` signifies an **object**. In order to call `push()`, you need an array instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t push into an object, to answer the question in the title.  Only into an array.

So, testCities.features needs to be an array.  Add a line that initializes it as such:

```
var testCities = {};
testCities.type = 'FeatureCollection';
testCities.features = [];
```

If you look at your expected result, the first character after “features”: is an open *square* bracket (so, features has to be an array).

Answer (score 0):

initialize a **feature** property to **testCities** like:

testCities.features = [];

features would be an empty array after this statement to which you can push any object.